# How to store the products at specific location using store block of material handling library in anylogic which are specified in database?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am trying to store specific SKUs at "specific slots" location through "store" block in AnyLogic. I have an excel sheet in which data of specific SKUs locations are available. I want to get the storage according to the data I am having in the sheet. How can I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDwUN.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)